# How to install Scaled Sitecore 10.1 XP on AWS without kubernetes / dockers?

Tags: deployment, amazon-web-services

For setting up Sitecore on Azure we have ARM templates or through marketplace we can easily setup scaled Sitecore instance. How we can achieve same with AWS? I found one reference [Sitecore XP 9.3 On AWS](https://aws.amazon.com/quickstart/architecture/sitecore-xp-v93/) but not sure if same we can use for Sitecore 10.1.

I found few reference of setting up Sitecore using kubernetes eks for Amazon, but without using docker/kubernetes can we achieve same using native way which we follow for Azure like using ARM templates etc Or there is totally different way which we need to follow for AWS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sitecore runs well on `AWS` however there are not as many resources out there which you can leverage as there are for Azure. If you want to use `CloudFormation` which is similar to what `ARM` is for Azure then the one reference you mentioned can be a great starting point, however you will have to update it for `Sitecore 10.1`. The Github repo can be  found [here](https://github.com/aws-quickstart/quickstart-sitecore-xp).

There is not a single way you need to follow. Different projects run Sitecore on AWS in complete different deployments e.g. `EKS`, `EC2`, `ECS`, `ElasticBeanstalk` etc.